# Conservation of the Feller property after passage to the limit

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, semigroups-of-operators

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ $(d\geq 1)$ be a compact set, $(D,\|\cdot\|_{\infty)}$ be the set of continuous functions form $[0,1]$ to $K$ endowed with the topology of the supremum norm, and $\mathcal{C}$ the set of continuous real functions on $K$. Let $(X^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in D^\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of Markov processes (with regards to their natural respective filtrations $\mathcal{F}^n=(\mathcal{F}^n_t=\sigma(X_s^n,\,0\leq s\leq t))_{t\geq 0}$).

Assuming that their respective semi-groups $(P_t^n)_{t\geq 0}$ have the Feller property (according to Liggett: for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $t\geq 0$, if $f\in\mathcal{C}$, then $P_t^n f\in\mathcal{C}$), and that $(X^n)$ converges in law to $X$, a Markov process in the sense of its own natural filtration, has the semi-group of $X$ the Feller property?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't think this is true. Think of $g_n$ as a sequence of continuous functions from $[0, 1]$ to $K$ that converges to a discontinuous function $g$. Take $P_t^n(x) := \delta_{t g_n(x)}$ (where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure). The limit is $P_t(x) = \delta_{t g(x)}$ which is not continuous. As for real-valued functions, I guess one requires some kind of uniform continuity of $P_t^n$.

Comment: I do not think that $P^n$ is associated to a Markov process in $D$ since $P^n_0(x)=\delta_0\neq\delta_x$. Do I understand your definition correctly?

Comment: Perhaps I slightly misunderstood your setting. (Maybe the counterexample can be salvaged if $P_0^n(x) = \delta_0$ is a problem, just set $P_t^n(x) := \delta_{t g_n(x) + x}$. I also realize, $g_n$ should probably map from $K$ to $K$.) In any case, what I was roughly trying to say was, if one wants continuity to be preserved under limits, it is usually not sufficient to assume continuity of each element in the sequence. I would expect (as for real valued functions) that one requires a stronger notion of convergence or continuity.